# Laravel clear package auto-discovery cache of composer packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autodiscovery

I wanted to remove a package from laravel. I did `composer remove vendor/package`

It was all good on my dev,  but when I deploy on production something went wrong and I cannot do anything now.

when I run

```
php artisan package:discover
```

I'm geting

> In ProviderRepository.php line 208:
>
> Class 'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider' not found

I'm guessing I it is something to do with some kind of cache or maby config

but I cannot run this command,

```
php artisan config:clear
```

because I'm getting the same error message as above.

PS. I'm using Laravel 5.6

Comment: Does Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider exist in config/app.php

Comment: no, that is why everything is working fin on my dev

Comment: Can you post the actual package name and how your composer require and app config (service providers) look like after removal?

Comment: Probably there's still something in the cache folders. I think that if you rename the files within `bootstrap\cache` they will be generated again (not tested).

Comment: Delete the cache files from your production environment `rm bootstrap/cache/*.php`

Comment: Deleting files sounds like an only option I left with. What files should I delete and how should I regenerate them afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed my problem deleting a config file like so:

```
$rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

This file is basically a cache for config, if you want to have this file built for you just run a following artisan command:

```
$php artisan config:cache
```

Answer (score 3):

You may need clear the autoloader files if they get jammed up as it is looking at those cached files when `php artisan config:clear` runs, thus creating the jam.

Remove the following files and they will rebuild:
`/bootstrap/cache/packages.php`
`/bootstrap/cache/services.php`

Comment: Thank you, I fixed my problem by deleting bootstrap/cache/config.php, I posted another answer here. The funny thing is that config.php does not exist on my dev but it was a problem maker on my prod.